# Javascript change title then f12 see change, but ctrl + u do not see any change

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, title

I have changed title in javascript web, then I have seen changes when choose F12
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YMqb.jpg

but i choose ctrl U, do not see any change
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSsfX.jpg

hepl me pls, thank all

Comment: If the title is changed using JavaScript, the new title won't appear in the source view, only in the inspector in the developer tools. View source shows the static document sent by the server.

Comment: thank bro, so I can not change title when load a partial view, is it true? or else to change it, pls hepl me

Comment: If you want to change the title that appears when you press Ctrl+U, you have to change it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the title via Javascript it is only in the DOM that this change will be reflected.
What you see when you press CTRL+U is the actual source of the page. This will not be changed by simply updating the title in the DOM.

Comment: thank bro, pls tell me how to change title when load partial view update when choose CTRL + U

Answer (score 0):

**F12** *(Inspect)* will let you see the current code and everything of the page whereas **Ctrl+U** *(View Source)* will let you see the actual source that was sent from the web server to your browser.

That is the reason why you will see changes in your browser when you use **F12** but not in the **Ctrl+U**.

Comment: thank bro, pls tell me know how to change title when load partial view